# MyBatis RowBounds doesn't limit query results

Tags: sql, spring, oracle, mybatis

I am developing an stateless API that needs to support pagination.

I use an Oracle database. 
I use Spring with MyBatis for database access.

From the documentation, I understand that I can use the RowBounds class to limit the number of rows returned by the query.

However, it seems that there's no special optimization done to the query to support pagination.

For example, if I set RowBounds to offset 100 with 50 records, I'd expect the query to have the following added:

```
(original query with the where clause...)
and ROWNUM < 150
and ROWNUM >= 100
```

But there's nothing there, it's just the query that I defined manually.

This is terrible for performance, since I might have several thousand results.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`Mybatis` leaves many things up to the `SQL driver` that is being used, and it appears the exact behavior surrounding`RowBounds` is one of those.

See http://mybatis.github.io/mybatis-3/java-api.html, particularly the section that says:

> Different drivers are able to achieve different levels of efficiency
>   in this regard. For the best performance, use result set types of
>   SCROLL_SENSITIVE or SCROLL_INSENSITIVE (in other words: not
>   FORWARD_ONLY).

The default is apparently `UNSET`, but you could try to use `SCROLL_SENSITIVE` as the `ResultSetType` attribute in the `select` tag and see if that helps. See http://mybatis.github.io/mybatis-3/sqlmap-xml.html for more info on that.

If that doesn't work you can always work around the issue by ditching the use of `RowBounds` and implement a **SettingsBean** class (or similar) that your `select` tag would take as a `parameterType`, and which contains fields for the `offset` and `limit` (or perhaps `rowStart` and `rowEnd` make more sense for `Oracle`, and then you can set those at runtime as needed and interpolate them dynamically into the SQL at the time the `select` is executed.

While a bit more code, you get to control the behavior exactly as you want through pure dynamic SQL. I have used an approach like this with `Mybatis` and `Postgres` and it has worked well.

So you would implement your **SettingsBean** class with those fields and their getters and setters, and your `select` statement might then look something like:

```
<select
  id="selectFoo"
  parameterType="com.foo.bar.SettingsBean">

select *
from foo
where rownum >= #{rowStart}
  and rownum < #{rowEnd}
</select>
```

Comment: Thanks. It seems that RowBounds will never use the Oracle rownum technique. Additionaly, It appears that the resultSetType setting is only relevant for stateful, web-based applications, like a web page showing paginated results. I'm using stateless EJBs with Spring & MyBatis, so I gather it will make 0 difference in my case? Seems like I will have to revent back to using rownum solution. I really think the MyBatis team should communicate the limitations of RowBounds more clearly. They describe it as a simple abstract way to do pagination, while in fact it is of very limited use.

Comment: Sure, no problem. In theory, even in a stateless application, it could work -- there would just need to be sequential queries with different `offset`s in conjunction with a `limit`. However it would really depend on how the `Oracle` driver handles it, as the number of rows to fetch at once rests with the `JDBC` layer, which in turn has a bunch of dependencies on the individual drivers (`Oracle`, `Postgres`, etc.). I agree it's made out to be simpler than it is. I've found that to also be the case with `Mybatis` when it comes to mappers for more complex types, such as String arrays.

Answer (score 6):

I found a simple work around to this issue.  I had followed the Mybatis instructions @khampson recommended and was passing a RowBounds instance to the mapper with no limits being enforced.

```
RowBounds rowbounds = new RowBounds(0, resultLimit);
roster = tableMapper.selectAll(rowbounds);
```

mapper java

```
public List<Row> selectAll(RowBounds rowbounds);
```

mapper xml

```
<select id="com.TableMapper.selectAll" resultMap="row" timeout="10">
            SELECT * FROM table;
</select>
```

simply appending "LIMIT #{param1.offset}, #{param1.limit}" to the mapper's xml produced the behavior I wanted!

```
<select id="com.TableMapper.selectAll" resultMap="row" timeout="10"> 
    SELECT * FROM table LIMIT #{param1.offset}, #{param1.limit}; 
</select>
```

Answer (score 1):

I tested on **Postgres database** and pagination from AngularUI. The first page is N°1, if you call page N°0, the services return all datas.

**java Service:**

```
public List<Foo> selectAll(int currentPage, int itemsPerPage);
    int offset = (currentPage - 1) * itemsPerPage;
    RowBounds rowbounds;
    if(currentPage == 0){
        rowBounds = new RowBounds();
    } else {
        rowBounds = new RowBounds(currentPage, itemsPerPage);
    }
    return fooMapper.selectAll(rowBounds);
}
```

**java Mapper:**

```
public List<Foo> selectAll(RowBounds rowbounds);
```

**xml Mapper:**

```
<select id="selectAll" resultMap="Foo">
    SELECT * FROM foo;
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

`Rownum` is a pseudocolumn in Oracle meaning it's added to the resultset in the last stage. This means, comparing `rownum` to anything bigger than 1 always returns no records. There are 2 options to modify your SQL statement:

1. Wrapping rownum as nested query:

```
select * 
  from (
        select a.*, ROWNUM rnum 
          from .... a
         where ...
           and ROWNUM <=  :max_rows
         order by -- important 
       )
 where rnum  >= :offset
```

where `:max_rows` is `offset + page size`.

2. Using analytical function:

```
  select *
    from (
            select a.*, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY id) rnum
              from ....
             -- order by is not important here
         )
   where rnum between 30 and 50;
```