# Fetching all the records on the next button also

Tags: java, ibatis, displaytag

I am developing an application in which for displaying I'm using **`displaytag`** library and for querying the data from database, I'm using **`Ibatis`**. 
I'm having around `10k` records in my database. On the **`UI`** I'm having the links to go to next and previous pages but the prob is when I go to next page or previous,on every click on the paginated links like (Page 1, 2, 3..., Next) , My application is loading every `10k` records. Means every click is fetching all `10k` records.

Is there anything I'm missing or is there any other way to try with?

Here is my `Jsp`:

```
    <sfdisplay:table name="userList"  
                                      pagesize="10"
                                      requestURI="/viewUserList.do"
                                      uid="listOfValues"
                                      sort="list"
                                      decorator="com.xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx" excludedParams="password confirmPassword " >
                            <sfdisplay:setProperty name="basic.empty.showtable" value="true" />              

                            <sfdisplay:column property="userName" titleKey="userlist.column.label.username" sortable="true" />
                            <sfdisplay:column property="firstName" titleKey="userlist.column.label.firstname" sortable="true" />
                            <sfdisplay:column property="lastName" titleKey="userlist.column.label.lastname" sortable="true" />
                            <sfdisplay:column property="orgs" titleKey="userlist.column.label.orgs" sortable="false" />
                            <sfdisplay:column property="modules" titleKey="userlist.column.label.modules" sortable="false" />
                            <sfdisplay:column property="roles" titleKey="userlist.column.label.roles" sortable="false" />
                            <sfdisplay:column property="action" titleKey="userlist.column.label.action" sortable="false" />

 </sfdisplay:table>
```

**Edit:**
I want to know if is there anything that can be done from JSP side which uses displaytag?

**Update** :
Here is the query :

```
<select id="selectUsers" resultClass="user"> SELECT u.user_id as userId, u.name as userName, u.first_name as firstName, u.last_name as lastName, u.LOCKED_AT_DATE as lockedAt FROM users u WHERE u.deleted IS NULL </select>
```

and Here is the updated jsp for **partial list implementation**

```
<sfdisplay:table name="userList"  
                                  pagesize="10"
                                  requestURI="/viewUserList.do"
                                  uid="listOfValues1"
                                  partialList="true"
                                  size="resultSize"
                                  sort="external"
                                  defaultsort="1"
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MyBatis RowBounds doesn't limit query results](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24301787/mybatis-rowbounds-doesnt-limit-query-results)

Comment: @Charlie, I tried that answer but didnt work.

Comment: What do you mean didnt work? For what it's worth, Ibatis seems to be end of life so it's hard to find documentation. Have you tried a LIMIT(10) on your query? Can you include your query code in the question?

Comment: @Charlie Here is my Query:

<select id="selectUsers"  resultClass="user">
                                SELECT
                                u.user_id as userId,
                                u.name as userName,
                                u.first_name as firstName,
                                u.last_name as lastName,
                                u.LOCKED_AT_DATE as lockedAt
                                FROM users u
                                WHERE
                                u.deleted IS NULL
                </select>

Comment: @Charlie  I tried LIMIT(10) in my query but it didnt work.

Comment: Can you be more specific about what didnt work? Did the query fail? Did it produce an error? was the result set not what you expected? Was the result set not limited to 10?

Comment: @Charlie, Yes it didnt give the result set with limited to 10

Comment: The select element you have pasted into the comments (which should be part of your question) doesn't indicate a limit is used.

Comment: As @Charlie said please read [How to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and support us a full working example. There is no glue code between ibatis and the jsp pages, there is no real effort in trying to understand the limiting of sql queries. Which database do you use?

Comment: @beendr I agree and I was new to this so only I did mistakes in posting question.
I am using MS-Sql 2014

Answer (score 0):

Displaytag "cuts" the 10 elements out of your 10k elements. And this has to be done for every request. That's why it is so slow. The `userList` will just contain all 10k users if you ibatis query is just something like `select * from users`.

**Recommendation #1**: In Ibatis implement some sort of paging with a offset feature. Nearly every database has this (e.g. mysql uses `LIMIT`). With that function you should be able to access just *some* elements from the 10k table in the database and not all of them.

**Recommendataion #2**: For "customized" paging (and sorting) you have to use the partialList feature of displaytag. Therefore you have to implement the paging feature and tell displaytag on which page your query was selecting the data on the server side. ([Example](http://www.displaytag.org/1.2/tut_externalSortAndPage.html))

These recommendations will take some time to implement, but if you are stuck to this sort of tools and the user table will grow in the next time, that's the only option I see.

Comment: I tried the Recommendation #2 and in that i used partial list approach. Is there an thing like this implementation will show the same data on every page links? I mean I'm seeing the same data on page 1, 2 ,....etc

Comment: I'm sorry I didn't expressed that correctly. You have to implement recom#1 and #2. And #1 before #2. Could you change your question to show us how you have implemented the queries? And how you've implemented the partialList?

Comment: I figured out the solution for partial list implementation, I was using displaytag1.1.1.jar and it was not compatible with partial list implementation. I changed this to displaytag1.2.jar file and i am getting now different data on every page links.

Comment: But still on every page click whole data is is getting queried and not partially and its affecting the performance badly.

Comment: Here is the Ibatis query, 

<select id="selectUsers" resultClass="user">
  SELECT
  u.user_id as userId,
  u.name as userName,
  u.first_name as firstName,
  u.last_name as lastName,
  u.LOCKED_AT_DATE as lockedAt
  FROM users u
  WHERE
  u.deleted IS NULL
 </select>