# How to use expression as OFFSET in MySQL?

Tags: java, mysql, sql, pagination, mybatis

I am using MyBatis.

I want to do pagination using the `page` and `size` arguments.

I want to write the following SQL code:

```
SELECT * FROM person LIMIT 10 OFFSET 10 * 0
```

In MyBatis, It will be:

```
SELECT * FROM person LIMIT #{size} OFFSET #{page} * #{size}
```

But this is not the corrent SQL grammer.

So how to do this?

Comment: possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24301787/mybatis-rowbounds-doesnt-limit-query-results

Answer (score 1):

I believe what you're looking for (in MySQL) is:

```
SELECT * FROM person LIMIT 10, 10;
```

From the MySQL documentation:
[SELECT syntax](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/select.html)

Basically, `LIMIT offset, rowcount`

Sorry, is this question for MySQL or MyBatis?

Answer (score 0):

The pagination syntax for MySQL is:

```
SELECT * FROM person LIMIT <offset>, <number-of-rows>
```

Your MyBatis query should look like:

```
SELECT * FROM person LIMIT #{page} * #{size}, #{size}
```